# Is this a correct way of JavaScript/jQuery callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback

This is a simple question. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    func1( "foo", callback);

    function callback(param){
        alert(param+" is my name");
    }

    function func1(name, cb) {
        cb(name);        // alerts "foo is my name"
        callback("bar"); // alerts "bar is my name"
    }
});
```

I want to know:

- Which one of the function calls inside `func1` is the correct `callback` and why?
- Or are they both correct?
- Isn't `callback("bar");` a normal function call?

Comment: They're technically the same in your situation because `callback` and `cb` refer to the same function. But in the scenario where everything is not in the same scope, you usually want to use `cb(name)` because you don't know what `cb` will be (other than it's a function), and it will just be whatever is passed to `func1`. You can also leverage using `.call()` and `.apply()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Are you not able to find this information online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks are meant to let a caller specify what a function should do at some defined point in that function's execution. The function being called shouldn't know the name of that callback function ahead of time. So they'll often be passed to a function as an argument and the function that's supposed to *call* the callback should just invoke that argument.

When you call `callback("bar")` in `func1`, you're totally missing the point of callbacks. You may be invoking the function that you happen to use as a callback, but the point of callbacks is that `func1` isn't supposed to know about that. It's just supposed to call the function that's been passed in as an argument (`cb`). When I'm calling `func1` I should be able to pass a completely different callback function and `func1` should just call that function without knowing what its name is (it may not even have one!).

The "correct" way is `cb(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

`callback("bar");` is directly invoking the callback function where as `cb(name);` calls the reference passed to the `func1`,

`cb(name);` seems to be the correct way here.

Answer (score 1):

First one. Function calls another one which has been pased as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like most jquery methods follow this this form for callbacks:

```
 $(SUBJECT).method(function() {
     //do stuff
 }, /*callback here*/ function(){
    //do stuff
 });
```

like for instance

```
$(foo).click(function() {
      $(bar).fadeIn(300, function(){
         //call back here
      });
 });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremythuff/Eqs9J/)